# Downloading binary data stored in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, binary

I have a SQL Server 2008 database that stores binary data files in some of the tables.

To access these files, I received an application (EXE file) that by giving it an item number saves the matching binary file to my drive.

I assume it runs a query and save the results of it.

Is there a way to see what query the EXE is using or what columns and tables its using?

Thank you

Comment: What are you expecting for an answer here? Your question is extremely vague and all over the place. But no, you cannot write a query that will execute an exe.

Comment: I  am sorry - I tried again

Comment: Run SQL Server Profiler on your SQL Server instance to see exactly what queries are executed

Comment: The question makes a LOT more sense now. I agree with marc_s. Run profiler and you will be able to view the queries being executed against your server.